# How to not treat "(1)" in username in Powershell as a positional parameter

Tags: powershell

long story short, I have a problem with my SBS2011 Sharepoint. To fix, I need to run some PS commands as per this: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2011/08/17/http-error-503-accessing-company-web-on-sbs-2011-standard/

The problem is that my SBS accounts have copied themselves somehow so `spfarm` is now `spfarm(1)`.

So when I run (as per the instructions)

```
Set-SPManagedAccount -UseExistingPassword -Identity $env:userdomain\accountname
```

I'm actually running

```
Set-SPManagedAccount -UseExistingPassword -Identity $env:userdomain\spfarm(1)
```

which results in the powershell error

> Set-SPManagedAccount : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '1'.

I don't really know PS, so how do I use a username like `spfarm(1)` in the above command?

Comment: Is this correct `$env:mydomain`?

Comment: No - I've just realised the that. I will edit the question :)

Comment: Can you try `"$($env:userdomain)\spfarm(1)"` *(quotes included)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scripting engine is evaluating `spfarm(1)` as a function. To stop it from doing that you can enclose the parameter in double quotes

```
"$env:userdomain\spfarm(1)"
```

Now the engine still evaluates `$env:userdomain`but it doesn't treat `spfarm(1)`as a function.

While this might do most of the time, safer is to be explicit about what should be evaluated and change `$env:userdomain`to `$($env:userdomain)`. Finally the parameter becomes

```
"$($env:userdomain)\spfarm(1)"
```

Comment: I also found that `$env:userdomain\'spfarm(1)'` work too.

Comment: True, but I was about to post following [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-here-strings/) when variable expansion doens't return what you assumed it should return. Safest is to enclose it.